NextJS Prisma server actions issues
I am using a library called next safe actions for server actions in NextJS 14 while building a very simple form. I am using Prisma as my ORM, mongoDB as my database, and react-hook-form + zod for form creation and validation:
"use client";

import { z } from "zod";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { contactUsSchema } from "./validation";
import { createPatientAction } from "./createNewPatient";
import { useAction } from "next-safe-action/hooks";

type contactUsSchemaType = z.infer<typeof contactUsSchema>;

export default function ContactUsForm() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<contactUsSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(contactUsSchema),
  });

  const { execute } = useAction(createPatientAction);

  //we should here call like API or something...
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<contactUsSchemaType> = (data) => {
    execute({ email: data.email, password: data.password });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="form">
      <input className="input" placeholder="email" {...register("email")} />
      {errors.email && <span>{errors.email.message}</span>}

      <input
        className="input"
        placeholder="password"
        {...register("password")}
      />

      {errors.password && <span>{errors.password.message}</span>}

      <button type="submit">submit!</button>
    </form>
  );
}

The server action is:
import { contactUsSchema } from "./validation";
import prisma from "../../lib/db";

export const createPatientAction = actionClient
  .schema(contactUsSchema)
  .action(async ({ parsedInput: { email, password } }) => {
    try {
      await prisma.patient.create({
        data: { email, password },
      });
      console.log("success!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating patient:", error);
    }
  });

But I keep getting the following error:
Error creating patient: PrismaClientUnknownRequestError:
Invalid `prisma.patient.create()` invocation: 


Error occurred during query execution:        
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: AuthenticationFailed { user: "SCRAM failure: bad auth : authentication failed" }, transient: false })

Troubleshooting:

I don't believe it is an error with my env variable because I am able to communicate with my database when I test the database in a .ts file as suggested in Prisma documentation.
I do not think it is an error in my next-safe-actions code because it works fine if I replace the prisma post request in the server component with a console.log(data)

I believe it has something to do with authentication, even though it works fine???
Any help is greatly appreciated. Please, it is driving me nuts.

Does your database build fine? Using the npx prisma generate command?

yes, I don't believe it is a problem with Prisma to database connection
